# How to publish angular project from vscode to stackblitz?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

Stackblitz turning out to be a great tool for angular. It provides immense support to view angular project from GitHub.

Is there a way to directly publish angular app from vscode ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not yet. The API of stackblitz would provide such a functionality but nobody has created an extension for vs code yet to do so.

Also see John Papas Twitter-Post to what you are requesting:
https://twitter.com/John_Papa/status/974024490324840450

until now you will need to deploy it to github and then from there you can run it as stackblitz.

lets say your repository url is `https://github.com/myusername/my-repo` you can directly run it on stackblitz when you change the url to `https://stackblitz.com/github/myusername/my-repo`